# How to write JUnit for equals() of static inner class

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

I have this following

```
public class PlayerHandler {

  public static class PlayerValue {
    public String name;
    public String value;
    public String status;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        PlayerValue playerValue = (PlayerValue) o;
        return playerValue != null && StringUtils.equals(playerValue.name, name)
                && StringUtils.equals(playerValue.value, value) && StringUtils.equals(playerValue.status, status);
    }
}
```

}

**how to write jUnit for this ? Please help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private PlayerHandler.PlayerValue value;
private PlayerHandler.PlayerValue value2;

@BeforeTest(){
     value = new PlayerHandler.PlayerValue();
     value2 =new  PlayerHandler.PlayerValue();

     value.name = "name1";
     value.playerValue = "value1";
     value.status = "status1";
}

@Test
public void checkEquals(){     
     value2.name = value.name;
     value2.playerValue = value.playerValue;
     value2.status = value.status;

     assertEquals(value , value2 );    
}

@Test
public void checkThaNotEquals(){
     value2.name = "value2";
     value2.playerValue = "playerValue2";
     value2.status = "status 2";

     assertNotEquals(value , value2 );    
}

@Test
public void checkNotEqualsWithNull(){
     assertNotEquals(value , null);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sbjavateam. value = PlayerHandler.PlayerValue(); here PlayerValue is a class not method. It shows error - method call expected.

Comment: add new....         value = new PlayerHandler.PlayerValue();         value2 =new  PlayerHandler.PlayerValue();

Comment: Thank you so much.